# SQL DATEDIFF - How to return value as whole number

Tags: sql

I have written the following query, but I don't know how to return the value as a whole number...

```
SELECT `FirstName`, `Surname`,`DOB`, DATEDIFF( NOW(), `DOB`) /365.25 AS AGE
FROM CustomerAccount
```

This query returns the age as a floating point number, for example; 25.8891

How do I  get this value to return as 25?

Thank you

Comment: Note that that’s only an approximate age calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floor()`:

```
floor(DATEDIFF( NOW(), `DOB`) /365.25) as age
```

You might find [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) more convenient:

```
timestampdiff(year, dob, now()) as age
```